# Android - Redirecting to another screen after a certain time

Tags: android, redirect

Here is the scenario:

User enters the registration page. After filling out his/her details (with data validation performed) user will press on the "Register" button. At this time, this will cause the user data to be inserted into the database. After inserting, with a proper response from PHP, I would like to redirect user to a page where it says "You're now registered" but **user will then be directed to the login page after 5 seconds.** How do I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

just use

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(FontActivity.this,Font.class);
          startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly with some minor changes to the code given! =)

Answer (score 1):

Use jitendra sharma's suggestion if you want to do *exactly* what you're asking for. That's more or less what his code does.

I'd advice you to consider using a `Toast` notification instead though. I'm thinking that the user presses the "Register now" button and once the data has been added to the database, you can simply run the following code, which will show the `Toast` notification and switch to the next `Activity`.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You're now registered!", 1500); // 1500 = 1.5 second duration
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivityNAme.class));
```

Here's what a `Toast` notification looks like if you're in doubt:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Michell for introducing Toast. Now I can use Toasts on my app. This is a good alternate way though, but I managed to use jitendra sharma's way. THANKS a lot! =)

Answer (score 0):

For Android - Redirecting to another screen after a certain time you can use the code like the following
 Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),          SecondActivityNAme.class));
            }

```
    }, 0, 3000);
```